# ModEvasive / mod_evasive Not Saving Logs

Tags: linux, apache, mod-evasive

We just installed `mod_evasive` on our Bitnami stack and verified it is working with the mod_evasive test file (test.pl). It returns 403s as expected.

Unfortunately, we cannot seem to find any logs of mod_evasive working. The `DOSLogDir` is set to `/var/lock/mod_evasive` and permissions were set: `chown -R www-data:www-data`

We do not see any record of the mod_evasive test blacklists in the mail log, either.

Any ideas what is going on here? Is mod_evasive not working, or are the logs not being created?

Reference:

https://www.rapid7.com/blog/post/2017/04/09/how-to-configure-modevasive-with-apache-on-ubuntu-linux/
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/discourse/configuration/enable-modules/

Comment: Do you mean "/var/log/mod_evasive"? On my Ubuntu system that's the default entered in the evasive.conf file.